# XQuery - does xs:string* denote a sequence?

Tags: xquery, sequence

In xquery, does `xs:string*` denote a sequence?

eg

```
xdmp:document-get-collections(
uri as xs:string
) as xs:string*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `xs:string*` denotes this function returns a string sequence with zero or an arbitrary number of string items. `xs:string` (without modifier) allows exactly one string item, `xs:string?` zero or one, `xs:string+` at least one item.